# truncate the content before / or \ using javascript

Tags: javascript, slice

how to truncate the content before / or \ using javascript.
For example if we have values like

```
h200/u39087
j201\yu7860
l123/op0002
```

I should get only the values like as shown below

```
u39087  
yu7860
op0002
```

Comment: I suggest you start by looking into the substring and substr methods. Get started with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: I suggest you start by looking into regular expressions. Get started with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long hand way but works fine.

```
function truncate(string, letter)
{
var result = "";

for (var i = string.length; i > 0; i--)
{
   if (string[i] == letter) 
       break;
   else
       result += string[i]
}

return result;
}

console.log(truncate("463648/ujfjdjdn", "/"))
```

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape symbol, so you should escape this backslash in your strings like  that `\\`

And here is the solution for your problem.

**JS**

```
function truncateSlash(string) {  
  var res;

  if (string.indexOf("/") !== -1 ) {
    res = string.split("/")[1];
  } else if (string.indexOf("\\") !== -1) {
      res = string.split("\\")[1];
    }

  console.log(res);
}

truncateSlash('h200/u39087');
truncateSlash('j201\\yu7860');
truncateSlash('l123/op0002');
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `str` have the values:

```
str.replace("\\","/").split('/')[1]
```

will work for you

```js
var arr = ["h200/u39087",
  "j201\\yu7860",
  "l123/op0002"
];

arr.forEach(function(str){
  console.info(str.replace("\\","/").split('/')[1]);
});
```

Comment: I totally forgot the split method.

Comment: @Kinduser You can set array with any value you want.

Comment: Yeah, but you have mutated the original string, which contains **only one**  backslash.

Comment: I answered based on question